# Custom SquareView - children not behaving with match_parent || wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

So I needed a view to be always square and I wrote the following custom class

```
public class SquareView extends LinearLayoutCompat
{
    public SquareView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width  = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        if (width > height)
        {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
        }
        else
        {
            setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the children of the view that are using `match_parent` and `wrap_content` are no longer behaving correctly

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to your larger problem, not a way to fix your custom view.

`ConstraintLayout` supports sizing children to have a certain aspect ratio. If you want a square LinearLayout, you can just put it inside a ConstraintLayout and enforce a 1:1 aspect ratio.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#adjust-the-view-size

> ### Set size as a ratio
>
> You can set the view size to a ratio such as 16:9 if at least one of the view dimensions is set to "match constraints" (0dp). To enable the ratio, click Toggle Aspect Ratio Constraint (callout 1 in figure 10), and then enter the width:height ratio in the input that appears.
>
> If both the width and height are set to match constraints, you can click Toggle Aspect Ratio Constraint to select which dimension is based on a ratio of the other. The view inspector indicates which is set as a ratio by connecting the corresponding edges with a solid line.
>
> For example, if you set both sides to "match constraints", click Toggle Aspect Ratio Constraint twice to set the width be a ratio of the height. Now the entire size is dictated by the height of the view (which can be defined in any way) as shown in figure 11.